# Insert Document object into Document object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have data (isn't text/html) that allow me creating document (webpage), which has its own style, title and etc...

My approach was by creating a document object by js

```js
const document = document.implementation.createDocument(null, null, null);
```

because I want to isolate(avoid style collusion and etc...) the webpage I am building of my app which build the webpage, and go through the data to create element by element, so far everything is good. At exception how to render the built document?

The question is how can I render the document(DOM object) inside my app(default DOM object)?

Comment: it isn't clear to me what you are doing/trying to do. But the general way of embedding a document within an html document is to use `iframe`

Comment: I am trying to insert the created document inside the default one, using iframe doesn't help me much because the `iframe.contentDocument` isn't accessible at moment where I am building. is there any way to inject the created document inside the default one ?

Answer (score 0):

Append all html/css to documentFragment, then append or replace host app. Use a wrapper div and nested scss to prevent pollution. You mention title... yes some onload javascript should run to tweak injection.